# Accepting integers as keys of **kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Keywords [have to](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117441.html) be strings

```
>>> def foo(**kwargs):
...     pass
... 
>>> foo(**{0:0})
TypeError: foo() keywords must be strings
```

But by some black magic, namespaces are able to bypass that

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> SimpleNamespace(**{0:0})
namespace()
```

Why?  And *how*?  **Could you implement a Python function that can receive integers in the `kwargs` mapping?**

Comment: Wonder if any other python distribution exhibits the same behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleNamespace now rejects integer keyword keys. As Martijn supposed, [the original behavior was a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue31655). It seems that it was fixed by [bpo-31655: Validate keyword names in SimpleNamespace constructor](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/79ba471488b936abda5ba5234b1ea90cbc94cae6) in v3.9.0b2, and then [backported to 3.6](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3909#issuecomment-334962097).

Answer (score 9):

> Could you implement a Python function that can receive integers in the kwargs mapping?

No, you can't. The Python evaluation loop handles calling functions defined in Python code differently from  calling a callable object defined in C code. The Python evaluation loop code that handles keyword argument expansion has firmly closed the door on non-string keyword arguments.

But `SimpleNamespace` is not a Python-defined callable, it is defined [entirely in C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Objects/namespaceobject.c). It accepts keyword arguments directly, without any validation, which is why you can pass in a dictionary with non-string keyword arguments.

That's perhaps a bug; you are supposed to use the [C-API argument parsing functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html), which all do guard against non-string keyword arguments. `SimpleNamespace` was initially designed just as a container for the [`sys.implementation` data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.implementation)<sup>*</sup>, and wasn't really designed for other uses.

There might be other such exceptions, but they'll all be C-defined callables, not Python functions.

---

<sup>*</sup> The [`time.get_clock_info()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.get_clock_info) also runs an instance of the `SimpleNamespace` class; it's the only other place that the type is currently used.

Comment: You were right that this was a bug (fixed now)! I can't agree that `SimpleNamespace` is only intended to hold `sys.implementation` data, it's actually documented under [Additional Utility Classes and Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) even with some usage notes.

Comment: @wim: it was *originally* conceived as a one-off object for `sys.implementation`; it has since been adopted as a generic reusable object. That expanded use did expose issues like these however. It was almost certainly created

Answer (score 1):

No, kwargs cannot be integers. This answer, however, is designed as a (very) short history lesson rather than technical answer (for that, please see @MartijnPierter's answer).

The check was originally added in 2010, in [issue 8419](https://bugs.python.org/issue8419) ([commit fb88636199c12f63d6c8c89f311cdafc91f30d2f](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/fb88636199c12f63d6c8c89f311cdafc91f30d2f)) for Python 3.2 (and I believe Python 2.7.4 as well, but don't quote me on that), and simply checked that call kwargs were strings (and raised a value error if they weren't). It also added `PyArg_ValidateKeywordArguments` to C-api, which simply performed the above check.

In 2017, [issue 29951](https://bugs.python.org/issue29951) changed the error text for Python 3.7 from "keyword arguments must be strings" to "keywords must be strings" in [PR 916](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/916) ([commit 64c8f705c0121a4b45ca2c3bc7b47b282e9efcd8](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/64c8f705c0121a4b45ca2c3bc7b47b282e9efcd8)). The error remained a `ValueError` and it did **not** change the behaviour in any way, and was simply a small change to the error descriptor.

Comment: The change I'm looking for was between v3.6.3 and v3.6.4.  It changed the behavior of `SimpleNamespace(**{0:0})`, not `dict(**{0:0})`.